# How to power a 12V solenoid

Tags: arduino, solenoid

I bought 2 solenoid valves. I'm looking to turn them on/off using my relay. However, I'm not sure what the best way to power them would be. Do I plug them directly into the wall (after attaching a wall connector to the wires)?

I know wall outlets are 120V. So does that mean I need to get a converter?

EDIT: 
[http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B00827FP26](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00827FP26)
[http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B00004S1V2](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00004S1V2)

Those are the solenoid valves I'm using.

Comment: Rule for projects, do not plug anything directly into the wall. At some point you'll know when you can break the rule.

Comment: Hard to answer your question without knowing more about the solenoid valves.  Post a link to the datasheet, please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is listed as 12V DC solenoid so you definitely don't want to try plugging into AC mains directly as fire and/or death may follow. Unfortunately it doesn't seem to mention the coil current, if you have a multimeter you could set it to the 10A range and connect it to a car battery with the meter in series to measure.

But otherwise I have a solenoid of fairly similar size (although a gas one) and I just measured it as around 1.5A. I'd hazard a guess those would be under 2.5A so I think a 12V DC power supply with a current rating of 5A would be sufficient for the pair of them.

As you've already sorted out controlling a 5V relay using the Arduino it sounds like a power supply is all you need. They are available from most electronics stores, e-bay etc in many styles but here's an [example on Amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00D8322VG).

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to control the solenoid from an Arduino?  Or from the wall outlet?  Is this 12V DC or 120VAC.  Do you have a datasheet?

If you want to control a 12V solenoid from the Arduino, you'll need to get a GPIO to switch a 12V supply for you.  You can do this thru a transistor (smaller arduino IO voltage controlling the base of a MOSFET that's switching a 12V source).

Do you have a spec on the solenoid?  Also, have a look here at the switching circuit.  Plenty of information out there re: solenoid switching.

http://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/io/io_6.html

Comment: Incidentally, the flywheel diode is important.  A must have.  Also have a look at this post.  It's designed around arduino:  http://bildr.org/2012/03/rfp30n06le-arduino/

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more clear. I want to use a 5v relay controlled by an arduino to turn on/off the solenoid. I just need a way to supply 12v DC to the solenoid. I'll post the links to the products in my original question. thanks.

Comment: EDIT:  If you're going to use a relay, scrap the bit below about the MOSFET and use that.  The rest (below) still stands:   <snip>  Ok...well that's easy.  :) You need the MOSFET circuit to switch the thing using the GPIO on the Arduino.  So that part still stands.  Now you need a 12V supply.  If you have a 12V wall wart you can use that.  Have you checked out this post yet?  Discussed the topic nicely.   http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/78068/getting-12v-wall-wart-to-power-12v-solenoid-driven-by-arduino?rq=1  <snip>

Comment: ...And again, the diode is not optional.  Read up on Flyback diodes and inductive loads.